# Error with Picasso library in

Tags: android, json, picasso

I tried to display an ArrayList in Picasso with a RecyclerView, but I have a problem with Picasso.
How can I load the data from the ArrayList to Picasso?

this  is the Adapter

```
public class ImageViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<ImagesModule> imagesModules;
Context context;

public ImageViewAdapter(List<ImagesModule> imagesModules, Context context){
    super();
    this.imagesModules = imagesModules;
    this.context = context;}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imageitem, parent,false );
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );

    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ImagesModule imagesModule = imagesModules.get( position );
    Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(imagesModule.getAllimage()).into(holder.appImage));
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imagesModules.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView appImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.appimages);
     }}
```

and this is the module

```
public class ImagesModule

 {
public List<String> getAllimage() {
    return Allimage;}
public void setAllimage(List<String> allimage) {
    Allimage = allimage;}
List<String> Allimage = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
```

and here I get the JSON and add it to the ArrayList

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("im:image");
    List<String> allimage = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int j=0; i<imageArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject actor = imageArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = actor.getString("label");
        allimage.add(name);
        imagesModule.setAllimage(allimage);
    }
```

Comment: Where code Exeptions LogCat?

Comment: You have one imageview and you want to set array of images to that !

Comment: Yes ! how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get one image URL to load into Picasso, you cannot load a List.

Also, this class is basically a List, so just treat it as one.

```
public class ImagesModule extends ArrayList<String> {

}
```

Parsing - Two options, one module for all the images, or somehow deal with one module per entry datapoint

```
// TODO: Determine if you want one 'master' module for all the images
ImagesModule module = new ImagesModule(); 

JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // TODO: Determine if you want one module 'per entry'
    /*** ImagesModule module = new ImagesModule(); ***/
    JSONArray imageArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("im:image");

    for (int j=0; i<imageArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject actor = imageArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = actor.getString("label");
        module.add(name); // TODO: Actually get an image, not an actor probably...
    }
```

Now, you can load that String into Picasso

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ImagesModule imagesModule = imagesModules.get( position );

    final String img = imagesModule.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context).load(img).into(holder.appImage));
}
```

Comment: Still, I recommend Gson for deserializing the JSON.

Comment: Well, your other 10+ posts are showing images. I can't solve all your problems. I assume `name` is not a URL at `module.addImage(name);`

Comment: and in 
    final ImagesModule imagesModule = imagesModules.get( position );

 imagesModules.get( position ); imagesmodules cannot resolve

Comment: That would be a problem with your code. A variable is out of scope. I can't see your code, and I believe everything in my answer has a reference

Comment: `imagesModules` should resolve. Look inside `public ImageViewAdapter`, you have set that variable there. You may have re-named the variables between this and the other posts

Comment: Okay, I just had a thought. Depending on when you set the ImageAdapter after parsing the data, then you'll need to use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged` on the `ImageViewAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

use below code in `onBindViewHolder()`

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imagesModule.getAllimage().get(position).into(holder.appImage);
```